# Executing a SQL query with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to add some information to my database. I searched for some tutorials, but none of them work.

NonQuery can do what he needs to do, because the messagebox returns "Success" (1). But it does not update my database. If I put the same query to "Add New Query", directly to my database, it works.

Can someone help me?

My class code at the moment:

```
namespace BurnThatFat
{
    class databaseconnection
    {
        //fields
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionstring;

        public databaseconnection()
        {
            // fields waarde toewijzen
            connectionstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
                @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            OpenConnection();
            CloseConnection();
        }

        public List<Object> getObjectsFromDatabase()
        {
            try
            {
                OpenConnection();
                // sql query
                // Datareader
                // sqlcommand
                // return list van objecten , objecten veranderd naar jouw wens van data.
                CloseConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return new List<object>();
        }

        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void AddGebruiker()
        {
            string query = "insert into Gebruiker VALUES(3, 'Cihan', 'Kurt', 18, 'Man', 85, 75, 'Admin1', 'Test123', 'testen');";
            using (connection)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                OpenConnection();
                int resultaat = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (resultaat == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("succes");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("fail");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

And this is the code for my buttons etc:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// voor sql connectie.
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace BurnThatFat
{
    public partial class SignUp : Form
    {

        databaseconnection db = new databaseconnection();

        public SignUp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gb_login.Visible = false;
            gb_Voornaam.Visible = false;
            gb_Achternaam.Visible = false;
            gb_leeftijdgeslacht.Visible = false;
            gb_gewicht.Visible = false;
            gb_email.Visible = false;
            gb_Start.Visible = true;


        }


        private void btn_SignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gb_Start.Visible = false;
            gb_Voornaam.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gb_Start.Visible = false;
            gb_login.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btn_loginvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gb_login.Visible = false;
            // hier moet nog een GB!!!!!!
        }

        private void btn_voornaamvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            gb_Voornaam.Visible = false;
            gb_Achternaam.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btn_achternaamvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gb_Achternaam.Visible = false;
            gb_leeftijdgeslacht.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btn_leeftijdvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gb_leeftijdgeslacht.Visible = false;
            gb_gewicht.Visible = true;
        }


        // einde registratie
        // opslaan van gegevens in database
        private void btn_emailvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // gebruiker = new Gebruikerklasse();
           // gebruiker.Naam = Convert.ToString(tb_voornaam.Text);
           //// gebruiker.Achternaam = Convert.ToString(tb_achternaam.Text);
          //  gebruiker.Leeftijd = Convert.ToInt32(nud_leeftijd.Value);
          ///  gebruiker.Geslacht = Convert.ToString(cb_geslacht.Text);
          //  gebruiker.Huidig_gewicht = Convert.ToInt32(nud_huidiggewicht.Value);
          //  gebruiker.Streef_gewicht = Convert.ToInt32(nud_streefgewicht.Value);
          ///  gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam = Convert.ToString(tb_gebruikersnaam2.Text);
          //  gebruiker.Email = Convert.ToString(tb_email.Text);
         //   gebruiker.Wachtwoord = Convert.ToString(tb_wachtwoordsignup.Text);

            db.AddGebruiker();
            gb_email.Visible = false;
            // hier moet nog een GB!!!!!

        }

        private void btn_gewichtvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gb_gewicht.Visible = false;
            gb_email.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So many things you should do differently here. First, your connection string belongs in a config file, not hard coded. You should wrap your connection in a USING statement and not have separate methods to open and close connections. You have very brittle architecture here that can very easily clog up your connection pool due to poorly handling connections.

Comment: Why are you catching `MySqlException` if you're using MS SQL Server?

Comment: And why is this tagged as sql server but you are catching mysql exceptions? If this is actually sql server those exceptions will never happen. Look at the catch block in OpenConnection. If you actually catch the exception and the number is anything other than 0 or 1045 your catch block will do nothing other than return false rendering you helpless to debug this.

Comment: Unless this is a learning exercise when possible avoid using SQL directly and opt for one of the ORMs out there, such as EntityFramework. It's easier to maintain and you don't have to deal with SQL injection etc

Comment: The `INSERT` statement doesn't list the columns before the values.

Comment: This is an exercise for school. I really dont understand C# with databases. I have to use the Microsoft SQL database, can't use another one. 

I dont need to name the columns, because I have to use all the columns, not specific ones

About the catch exception with MYSQL,
A classmate gave me a part of his code, to test. He uses MYSQL. I didnt even see that. I changed it to Sql, but still not solving my problem.

Comment: @Amy: It is not necessary if you provide values for each column.

Comment: @Gitex: Then you should use `SqlException` instead of `MySqlException` and better remove the reference for MySql from your project to avoid using the wrong classes.

Comment: @Gigitex While it's not required to list the column names, you should *always* list them out.  This avoids issues with the queries no longer working if the table structure changes, and helps protect against inserting data into the wrong column.  School assignment or not, it's a good habit to get into early.

Comment: @Siyual done that :)
 string query = "insert into Gebruiker([Gebruiker-ID], Naam, Achternaam, Leeftijd, Geslacht, Huidig_gewicht, Streef_gewicht, Gebruikersnaam, Email, Wachtwoord) VALUES(3, 'Cihan', 'Kurt', 18, 'Man', 85, 75, 'Admin1', 'Test123', 'testen');";

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to insert into a SQL Server database:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

string commandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name, Address) VALUES (10, 'Bob', '123 Main Street');";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

As long as `commandText` is a working query, it should insert a row. It would be better to use parameters for your values instead of hard coding them like I did here - that avoids SQL injection attacks and other potential problems. You can search Google for that (or the question you are asking now) and find tons of resources to help you.

If you need more specific help, post details such as what is actually happening when you try to run your code - are you getting an exception?

Comment: I have this now:
http://prnt.sc/drz4b5
http://prnt.sc/drz4ok

Still does not upload anything to my database.

Comment: Try setting a break point on the line "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" to make sure that it is being run.  If not, make sure that AddGebruiker() is being called by something - it looks like your button click should make it run, but only if you are handling the "Click" event properly.

Comment: If i press on 'send ' it should update the database. But that doesnt happen. It happens to be a bit laggy, but that means that the connection is opened and closed... if I refresh my database, nothing is added.

Comment: Set a break point to make sure that your button is doing what you think it is.  If the insert does not work, it should be throwing an Exception and crashing your program.  If it is running, check your connection string - it looks different than any connection string that I normally use.  You can use Server Explorer in Visual Studio to find your connection string - click on the database that you want and it should appear in the properties window.

Comment: It does exactly the same thing with a breakpoint. I will try to change the connectionstring and come back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd clean up a bunch of things before doing anything else.

First, get rid of the openconnection and closeconnection methods all together.  And don't keep an instance property for the connection in your class.  Create the connection ondemand with a using statement, because at the end of the using statement the compiler will insert a call to the Dispose method on the connection's IDisposable interface implementation and it will close the connection automatically for you.

So after cleaning up all the unnecessary code all you really should have in this class is an implementation of your Addgebrukier method which would look like this

```
public void AddGebruiker()
{
        string query = "insert into Gebruiker VALUES(3, 'Cihan', 'Kurt', 18, 'Man', 85, 75, 'Admin1', 'Test123', 'testen');";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                int resultaat = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (resultaat == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("succes");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("fail");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You should also load your connection string from the  section in the app/web.config, but you can do that later after you get it running.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but if I run your code it will give me an error. I'll need to have an open connection for ExecuteNonQuery or else it won't work

Comment: The connection variable and the `connection.Open();` is missing.

Comment: You're right I forgot the connection.Open.  Editing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple concept that should work perfectly fine for you.  Just change the ServerName, DatabaseName, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection ;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            string sql = null;
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            sql = "insert into product (Product_id,Product_name,Product_price) values(6,'Product6',600)";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show ("Row inserted !! ");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```